# Formatting controls in Windows forms Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am making a Forms application on Visual Studio 2015. How do I put the buttons inside highlighted 'Test Flow window' in the attached image?
[image]

I am new to the Studio and Windows forms and have tried exploring toolbox to do the same.
Thank You.

Comment: What does *Formatting controls* mean, in your view? *How do I put the buttons inside...* put Buttons inside a GroupBox? How did the current Controls end up there? Did you build that Form or does it belong to an existing Project you're trying to modify? -- Are you just looking for `[The GroupBox].Controls.Add([Some Button])`?

Comment: put Buttons inside a 'GroupBox' is what I needed. The image I posted is from another application I found online. I just wanted to put controls inside the groupbox in my own project to make things look more neat. I tried searching how to do that but it was of no avail. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can add Controls to a GroupBox (or any other container) in the Designer, just dropping a new Control from the ToolBox. At run-time, use `[Control].Controls.Add([Some Control])`, then specify *where* (`Location` and `Size`, aka `Bounds`)

Comment: Ok. Got it. Will do that. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tanbntu If you find a solution, you can write an answer by your self, See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it will also help others to solve the similar issue.